# bash script, create array of all files in a directory

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, while-loop

I have a directory `myDir`   of many .html files. I am trying to create an array of all the files in the directory so I might be able to index the array and be able to refer to particular html files in the directory. I have tried the following line:

```
myFileNames=$(ls ~/myDir)

for file in $myFileNames; 
#do something
```

but I want to be able to have a counter variable and have logic like the following:

```
 while $counter>=0;
   #do something to myFileNames[counter]
```

I am quite new to shell scripting and am unable to figure out how to achieve this hence would appreciate any help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 62):

You can do:

```
# use nullglob in case there are no matching files
shopt -s nullglob

# create an array with all the filer/dir inside ~/myDir
arr=(~/myDir/*)

# iterate through array using a counter
for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    #do something to each element of array
    echo "${arr[$i]}"
done
```

You can also do this for iteration of array:

```
for f in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: If you want to limit the number of times the for loop is run you could make the following ammendment:
    
    counter=10

    for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]} && i<counter; i++)); do

Comment: Actually **`shopt -s nullglob`** can be used before array creation to avoid getting any false result.

Comment: Maybe you can tell how to filter files with certain extension?

Comment: To match files with `txt` extension use `arr=(~/myDir/*.txt)` at top

Comment: This solution works for me except that the array contains the file path along with the file name.  How would I store just the file name and not the path?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then it is better to do `cd myDir` and then `arr=(*.txt)`

Comment: btw, if there is no matching file the array will just contain `~/myDir/*`.. Might be unexpected.

Comment: @HenkPoley: Good point. I have added `shopt -s nullglob` for this.

Comment: what if files need sudo to list them?  e.g. `sudo ls`, how would i use shopt and set the array for this?

Comment: Run this script with `sudo`

Answer (score 8):

Your solution will work for generating the array.  Instead of using a while loop, use a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=($( ls * )) #Add () to convert output to array
counter=0
for i in $files ; do
  echo Next: $i
  let counter=$counter+1
  echo $counter
done
```

Comment: Use IFS to set the field separator in this case. So long as IFS doesn't include space, then you should be good.

Comment: OP didn't mention this as being part of the criteria :)

Answer (score 1):

```
# create an array with all the filer/dir inside ~/myDir
arr=(~/myDir/*)

# iterate through array indexes to get 'counter'
for counter in ${!arr[*]}; do
    echo $counter           # show index
    echo "${arr[counter]}"  # show value
done
```