# Getting the first match with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bash function that goes through a list of files and greps for a certain word and writes it into a file. The problem is I get every instance of the word, I just want to get the first instance. I came across a solution by adding `head -1` with the grep, but now, my function just hangs when I call it.

```
 83 function processAppLogs {
 84         for i in `find $log_des -name $fname`
 85             do
 86                 p=$i
 87                 d=${p//applog.txt/unmountTimestampList.txt}
 88                 grep "UNMOUNTED"  $i >> $d
 89                 grep "PATIENT ID" | head -1 | $i >> $d
 90             done
 91 }
```

I'm looking to grep only the first instance of "PATIENT ID" but I think I might have the syntax wrong? Is that the proper way to grep the first instance and write that to a file?

Comment: So what was the question here: how can I make this code work or how can I grep just once? `grep ... | head` will grep all the file and then get the first match, whereas `grep -m1` is more optimal since it stops as soon as it finds the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side not to @fedorqui's answer.

What you got wrong is the order of commands. The `head` must occur after the `grep` and then should the redirection come. Like

```
grep "PATIENT ID" $i | head -1  >> $d
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `-m 1` to indicate that you just want to match once:

```
grep -m 1 "PATIENT ID" >> "$d"
```

From `man grep`:

> **-m NUM**, --max-count=NUM
>
> Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.

#### Test

```
$ seq 8 12
8
9
10
11
12
$ seq 8 12 | grep 1 -m 1
10
$ seq 8 12 | grep 1 -m 2
10
11
```

Comment: Much more efficient this; `grep` will terminate at the earliest possible instant and you save on an additional shell `fork` and `exec` compared to the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `-m`, to specify a maximum number of matches, if your version of grep supports it. Otherwise, piping the output to `head` will work. `head` will exit after it reaches the number of lines specified, breaking the pipe and causing grep to exit, so the outcome will be the same (albeit at the expense of a pipe).

A portable alternative using a single process would be to use awk:

```
awk '/PATIENT ID/ {print; exit}' "$i"
```

Loops like `` for i in `find $log_des -name $fname` `` **should be avoided**, as they rely on well-behaved filenames (no spaces or glob characters present) and break otherwise.

If you're relying on find to do a recursive directory search, then use `globstar` instead, as it allows you to do what you want safely.

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/"$fname"; do
    d=${i//applog.txt/unmountTimestampList.txt}
    { grep "UNMOUNTED" "$i"; grep -m 1 "PATIENT ID" "$i" } >> "$d"
done
```

As a bonus I've also redirected a single block, rather than each command separately (perhaps you can use `>` instead now?) and safely quoted your variables.

Comment: Nice explanation! Note you could also probably do `while read ... do; done < <(find ...)`

Comment: @fedorqui thanks. The approach using `while read` still misses the (pathological) case of a newline in a filename and relies on external tools, so I still think that this is the best way in bash. The other safe alternative would be to use `-print0` with `find` but that's non-standard too.

Comment: Good point. I just started a bounty in [how to loop list of file names returned by find](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/1983854) so that we can have a canonical answer that we can always refer.