# how many files find found?

Tags: bash, unix, find

I'm writing a script where I want to error out if the file I'm searching for exists in multiple locations, and tell the user the locations (the find results).  So I've got a find like:

```
file_location=$(find $dir -name $file -print)
```

I'm thinking it should be simple to see if the file is found in multiple places, but I must not be matching what find uses to separate results with (seems like space sometimes, and a newline others).   As such, rather than matching on that, I want to see if there are any characters after $file in $file_location.

I'm checking for

```
echo "$file_location" | grep -q "${file}."; then
```

and this still doesn't work.   So I guess I don't care what I use, except I want to capture $file_location as a result of the find, and then check that.  Can you suggest a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
found=$(find "$dir" -name "$file" -ls)
count=$(wc -l <<< "$found")
if [ "$count" -gt 1 ]
then
  echo "I found more than one:"
  echo "$found"
fi
```

For zero matches found you will still receive a 1 because of the intransparent way the shell *strips* a trailing newline with the `$()` operator, so effectively one line output and zero lines output are both one line in the end.  See `xxd <<< ""` for demonstration of the automatic appending of a newline when used as input again.  A simple way to circumvent this is to add a fake newline in the beginning of the string, so no empty string can happen: `found=$(echo; find …)`, and then subtract one from the number of lines.

EDIT: I changed the usage of `-printf "%p\n"` in my answer to `-ls` which performs a proper quoting of newlines.  Otherwise file names with newlines in them would mess up the counting.

Comment: Thanks I'm liking this way the best.  I also test if the file wasn't found.  Do you know why count is still 1 if the file is not found?

Comment: I extended my answer to explain this wart.

Comment: May I ask how you'd compare your answer to:  if [[ $file_location == *${file}* ]]   ?

Comment: May I ask how you'd compare your answer to:  if [[ $file_location == \*${file}\* ]]   ?   I tried this after.  My question now properly showing the "*"

Comment: I would not use an equality comparison of a list with a string to find out of the list has exactly one element.  Too brittle and confusing for any other developer.

Comment: Thanks.  I like your answer addition.  My comparison is trying to see if the location contains any characters after the filename.  This seems brittle to you?

Comment: Ah, that's the intention.  Then I would prefer the `case` operator of the shell: `case "$file_location" in; "${file}"?*) echo "Yay!";; *) echo "nope";; esac`

Comment: The standard way to cover this case is by setting the `nullglob`. See Greg's wiki on this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob

Comment: @BroSlow, ...that's assigning find's output to a variable, Not a great idea to be newline-delimiting a list of filenames, but not a FAQ 50 violation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Guess it doesn't matter as much here, still errors with eol.

Comment: Sure -- if you have a filename with a newline, it'll count as two names, which is bad; I just didn't see why it was a FAQ-50 problem.

Comment: Format `%p` quotes newlines in filenames as `?`.  See the section `UNUSUAL FILENAMES` in the man page of `find` for details which way of outputting quotes how.  For my answer this means that it should work without any problem, even for the weirdest of possible filenames.

Comment: @Alfe Not a big issue, but that doesn't quite work here since `If the output is not going to a terminal, it is printed as-is`.

Comment: I stand corrected!  Then I'd propose `found=$(find "$dir" -name "$file" -ls)` which is ① shorter and ② gives out even more information.  And quotes newlines also on non-terminals ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like below if you want to avoid errors on eols and such

```sh
files=() 
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r match; do 
  files+=("$match") 
done < <(find "$dir" -name "$file" -print0) 
(${#files[@]} > 1) && printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Or in bash 4+

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob 
files=("$dir"/**/"$file") 
((${#files[@]} > 1)) && printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the full name in the `find` command, the matches on name will be unique. That is, if you say `find -name "hello.txt"`, just files named `hello.txt` will be found.

What you can do is something like

```
find $dir -name $file -printf '.'
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this will print as many `.` as matches are found. Then, to see how many files are found with this name it is just a matter of counting the number of dots you got as output.

Comment: I want to tell the user the locations, if there are more than one, that the find command finds.  Since find is a bit slow, I would like to run it once.

Comment: Uhms, you should have mentioned this in your question. You may want to go through [How to loop through file names returned by find?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/1983854)

Comment: @Ray it would be good if you update your question indicating what edge cases you want to cover. I mentioned that other question as it is the canonical. So probably the best solution is to store the results in an array, `var=( $(find ...) )` and then use the standard ways to count the number of elements in it and, eventually, print all its values.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `find` here if you're running a new (4.0+) bash which can do recursive globbing itself; just load glob results directly into a shell array, and check its length:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar # enable recursive globbing, and null results
file_locations=( "$dir"/**/"$file" )
echo "${#file_locations[@]} files named $file found under $dir; they are:"
printf '  %q\n' "${file_locations[@]}"
```

If you don't want to mess with `nullglob`, then:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursive globbing
file_locations=( "$dir"/**/"$file" )

# without nullglob, a failed match will return the glob expression itself
# to test for this, see if our first entry exists
if [[ -e ${file_locations[0]} ]]; then
  echo "No instances of $file found under $dir"
else
  echo "${#file_locations[@]} files named $file found under $dir; they are:"
  printf '  %q\n' "${file_locations[@]}"
fi
```

---

You can still use an array to unambiguously read `find` results on old versions of bash; unlike more naive approaches, this will work even when file or directory names contain literal newlines:

```
file_locations=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  file_locations+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -name "$file" -print0)
echo "${#file_locations[@]} files named $file found under $dir; they are:"
printf '  %q\n' "${file_locations[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using:

```
find . -name blong.txt -print0
```

Which tells `find` to join its output together with null `\0` characters.  Makes it easier to use `awk` with the `-F` flag or `xargs` with the `-0` flag.

Comment: Could you write the whole if statement please, saving the result of the find in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
N=0

for i in `find $dir -name $file -printf '. '`
do
    N=$((N+1))
done

echo $N
```

Comment: this is quite buggy and may fail in many cases, yet alone when the result contains spaces.

Comment: @fedorqui: I combined it with your post and added a space between the '.'

Comment: well then this has two problems: one is that you are not explaining anything at all about the answer; two is that you are assuming things that weren't said. OP mentioned the file name can contain spaces, but the `print '. '` doesn't make sense.

Comment: `-printf '. '` is a way to avoid dealing with filenames that aren't under control. It creates output of `. . . .` with one `.` per-found file.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, I know, I was using it myself in my answer. My point here is that saying `-printf '. '` without any kind of explanation was a bit... unexplained and looked weird (even though it would work).

Comment: This doesn't work for all directory names -- needs more quotes. Think about what happens if `$dir` or `$file` contains spaces. Yes, it solves the problem of unexpected characters in the output from `find`, but not that of unexpected content in the input variables.

Comment: @fedorqui Ah, I misunderstood that bit of your comment then, my apologies.