# Open searched files from the terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

In the terminal I have used the find command to search for files containing a certain word xyz.

```
find . name "*xyz*"
```

This gives me two results.

```
./xyz123.pdf
./uvwxyz.pdf
```

Is there a command to open the first or second result immediately? Like

```
open(1)
open[1]
```

or something?
Instead of

```
open xyz123.pdf
```

Comment: I think you could inspire you with list in Bash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find