# Iterate through subdirectories and execute an awk script against certain files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a directory named ../words that contains a number of subdirectories(words/blabla,words/blabla), in turn each subdirectory contains two types of files (.*1.txt) and (.*2.txt) . What I need, it is to execute an AWK script against each one of these files.

Could it be something like?

```
for d in words/*
do
    for f in .*[0-9].txt
    do
    awk -f script.awk ${f}
    done
done
```

Comment: So have you tried that?  Problem is that you are not using `$d`.  You could also use the `find` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your `for` statement structure and apply the awk script to each specified file, you can do the following:

```
for file in $(find words -type f -name ".*[12].txt"); do
    awk -f script.awk "$file"
done
```

The `find` command is useful for recursively looking through a directory for any pattern of files.

---

**Edit:** If your file names contain things like spaces, the above script may not process them properly, so you can do the following instead:

```
find words -type f -name ".*[12].txt" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do 
    awk -f script.awk "$file"
done
```

or using xargs:

```
find words -type f -name ".*[12].txt" -print0 | xargs -0 awk -f script.awk
```

This allows you to delimit your file names with null `\0` characters, so variations in name spacing or other special characters will not be a problem. (You can find more information here: [Filenames with spaces breaking for loop, and find command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343727/filenames-with-spaces-breaking-for-loop-find-command), or here: [Handling filenames with spaces](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html), or here: [loop through filenames returned by find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find)).

Comment: Never do do `for file in $(whatever)` as it fails for various file names such as those that contain spaces. Always do `whatever | while IFS= read -r file` instead or even better `whatever | xargs`.

Comment: You are right! And I made an edit above to offer an alternative as you suggested.

Comment: @EdMorton: Those suggestions still break for some filenames. (Note that filenames can even contain newlines.)

Comment: @ruakh The loop syntax I suggested will ONLY break for file names containing newlines and the xargs one doesn't even break for that when used with a `whatever` than can output nul-separated instead of newline-separated strings, e.g. `find -print0 | xargs -0`, hence "**even better** `whatever | xargs`".

Answer (score 1):

Given what you've told us so far, this should be all you need:

```
awk -f script.awk ../words/blabla/.*[12].txt
```

Comment: I dunno. `script.awk` might sincerely behave differently if all files are passed in a single call, vs. if each file is passed in a separate call.

Comment: Definitely and there are other considerations too but the OP has given us no clue what `script.awk` does, nor provided any sample input or expected output or even a concrete representation of her directory structure - hence "Given what you've told us so far"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to skip the intermediate directory level and just look under the subdirectories you can use max/min depth

```
$ find words -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*[0-9].txt' | xargs awk -f ...
```

Comment: yes, wasn't paying attention after the pipe. fixed.