# How to fix path contain space in 'find' command of Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have to work with path contain space character in Linux,
My command below are works fine for non-space path, but it will fail if path contain space.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( find "." -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ); do
    b=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print substr($1,3); }' )
    echo "This file contain <Modified date> <ActualSize Byte>   <FullPath>" > "$i"/"$b".txt
    find "$i" -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %s %n" >> "$i"/"$b".txt
done
```

This is my folders list.

```
.
./Folder 1
./Folder 2
./Folder 3
```

The error of script is below.

```
./xyz.sh: line 4: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
find: ./Folder: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 4: 1/.txt: No such file or directory
find: 1: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: 1/.txt: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 4: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
find: ./Folder: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 4: 2/.txt: No such file or directory
find: 2: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: 2/.txt: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 4: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
find: ./Folder: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: ./Folder/Folder.txt: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 4: 3/.txt: No such file or directory
find: 3: No such file or directory
./xyz.sh: line 5: 3/.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not loop over `find` command as `for i in $(find . -type f)` syntax, see [Bash Pit-falls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) Use `find` with `-print0`, to preserve special characters on folder/file names on a while-loop as below:-

See what the `man` page of `find` says about the `-print0` option:-

```
   -print0
          True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by
          a null character (instead of the newline character that -print
          uses).  This allows file names  that  contain newlines or other
          types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that
          process the find output.  This option corresponds to the -0 option 
          of xargs.
```

Use the same in a script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do

    # Your script goes here

done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Comment: Dear Inian, i'm now using `while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do
        echo $folder
        find "$folder" -type f > "$folder"/File.txt 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print0)` Now i can only output as "File.txt". I want to use the depth 2 as file name of the text file, is it possible ?

Comment: @NoppornPhantawee: Please post it as a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Inian for the reply, i posted new tread here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780041/how-to-use-the-depth-level-2-or-maxdepth-as-output-text-file-for-my-bash-script

Answer (score 0):

Just change IFS to non-space (found there: [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find/37210472#37210472)
):

```
IFS="\r\n"
```

Alsol Lame (but works) just adding a sed filter/unfilter on space chars

```
for ix in $( find "." -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | sed "s/ /%SPC%/g"); do
    i=$(echo "$ix" | sed "s/%SPC%/ /g")
    b=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print substr($1,3); }' )
    echo "This file contain <Modified date> <ActualSize Byte>   <FullPath>" > "$i"/"$b".txt
    find "$i" -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %s %n" >> "$i"/"$b".txt
done
```