# How to use the depth level 2 or maxdepth as output text file for my bash script below

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm now using the bash script below to create file listing in each level 2 depth directories and output as text file in each particular folders.

But, i can only name it as "File.txt"
How to use the level 2 depth directory as the output text file name

e.g. while list the files in /users/bin/ the output file should named "bin.txt"

here's the code that i'm using.

```
#!/bin/bash

    while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do 

    echo $folder find "$folder" -type f > "$folder"/File.txt 

    done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for (1) files in the present working directory (which will have no path component aside from `'.'`), and (2) the rest of the files in the level 2 directories. If for instance, you wanted to output your list of the files in the present directory to `pwd.txt` and each file in the level 2 directories to files with the respective directory names (e.g. `./dir1/file_a.txt` into `dir1.txt`), you could do something similar to the following in the body of your loop:

```
tmp="${folder%/*}"                        ## remove filename
lvl2name="${tmp##*/}"                     ## remove leading path components
[[ $lvl2name = '.' ]] && lvl2name="pwd"   ## handle files in pwd to pwd.txt
echo $folder find "$folder" -type f >> "$lvl2name.txt"
```

It is up to you to truncate any existing `"$lvl2name.txt"` files before each subsequent run of the script. You could make a previous call to `find . -maxdepth 2 -type d ...` before your enter you file loop to get the directory names or something similar.

Give it a try and let me know if you have questions.