# Recursively list files from a given directory in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know that it can be done using `ls -R path`. But I'm trying to learn the syntax and control structures of the shell language, so I'm trying to write my own code:

```
#!/bin/sh

arg=$1;

lsRec() {
    for x in $1*; do
        if [ -d "$x" ]; then
            lsRec $x;
        else
            echo "$x";
        fi
    done
}

lsRec $arg;
```

When I call the command `./ej2.sh ~/Documents/`, the terminal throws: `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Why I'm getting this error?, Am I missing something in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside: you've tagged the question `bash`, but your shebang line targets `sh`, and you're using (only) `sh`-compatible syntax.

Comment: Another aside: You only need `;` to terminate statements if you place _multiple_ statements on the same line (but note that `do` and `then` _do_ need a preceding `;` if placed on the same line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your algorithm is entering endless loop since `lsRec` function implicitly expects its argument to end in "/". First level works, as you pass path ending with "/" as input, but second level doesn't, as the path you're making recursive call with doesn't end in "/". What you could do is either add the slash when you make a recursive call, so it'll look like `lsRec $x/`, or (better yet) add the slash in the loop arguments as in `for x in $1/*; do` (as system generally ignores multiple adjacent path separators).

Moving forward, I'd advise you to quote the values (e.g. `for x in "$1/"*`, `lsRec "$x"`, `lsRec "$arg"`) to avoid issues when path contains whitespace characters. You'll get there when you create a directory with space in its name under directory hierarchy you're scanning.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that "for x in $1*" finds $1, if that makes sense? So it becomes an infinite loop.
There are two solutions:

- Check if x == $1
- Change the for loop to "for x in $1/*"

Because $1 is replaced by the argument passed to the function right? So if it sends "hello" then it becomes "for x in hello*".
Now, that is a globbing pattern and will select "hello" and thus an infinite loop.

The second solution works because "hello" becomes "hello/*" instead of "hello*".

This code works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

arg=$1;

lsRec() {
    for x in "$1"/*; do
        echo "$x"
        if [ -d "$x" ]; then
            echo "This is a directory:"
            lsRec "$x";
        else
            echo "This is not a directory:"
            echo "$x";
       fi
    done
}

lsRec "$arg";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The slash is still missing? :)

Comment: @mike.dld Ah yes. Fixed now. Thanks m8!

Comment: @mklement0 Better now?

Answer (score 2):

I think you created a fork bomb. Your code creates an infinite recursion.

You should change the code to:

```
#!/bin/sh
   arg=$1;

   lsRec() {
      for x in $1/*; do
        if [ -d "$x" ]; then
            echo "$x"  ## here you print the line
            lsRec $x; ## here you pass the contents and NOT the line itself
                        ## your programm was passing dirs without processing
                        ## over and over
        else
            echo "$x";
        fi
    done
}

lsRec $arg;
```