# Bash loop only working for first iteration

Tags: bash

I am trying to upload a bunch of files to an ftp server via lfpt. For this I loop over the files and call the upload script with the file as argument. This works only for the first file.

Here's the code:

```
files=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "0025-*.PDF" -newer timestamp)
for file in "$files"
do 
bash upload.sh "$file" ""
stat "$file" >> watchdog.log
done
```

And here the upload script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'upload of file' "$1" 'will start now'
lftp -e "set ftp:passive-mode true; set ftp:ssl-allow true; set ftp:ssl-force true; set ftp:ssl-protect-data true; set ftp:ssl-protect-list true; set net:timeout 10;
open -u XXX,XXX XXX;
cd '$2';
sleep 2;
put '$1';
bye"
echo "$1" written to folder "$2"
```

The file paths contain spaces and after the first iteration I get the error of an unkown command showing the path until the space (e.g., Unkown command ´example/test'. ; original path: example/test 2/file1.pdf). What do I get wrong?

Comment: try escaping the white space in the path with this: example/test\ 2/file1.pdf

Comment: add `-x` to the shebang to debug, i.e. `#!/bin/bash -x`

Comment: @Byakko_Haku: try escaping the white space in the path: this would only help if this can be automated because I get the paths from the find command

Comment: @FredrikPihl: Unfortunately this does not provide any further insights. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Related: [How to loop through file names returned by find?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui: Thanks! That helped a lot. Found a solution based upon the answer to the related question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issues by using

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -name "0025-*.PDF" -newer timestamp -exec bash -c 'upload.sh "$0" ""' {} \;
```

instead of the loop.

(Based upon the answer to [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find) - many thanks to fedorqui for pointing to this post in his/her comment)