# Bash - file path can not be read for LAME encoder

Tags: bash, lame

How do I properly escape the path to come out of `find` to a new command argument?

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(find . -type f -name '*.flac')
       do
           if flac -cd "$f" | lame -bh 320 - "${f%.*}".mp3; then
              rm -f "$f"
              echo "removed $f"
            fi
       done
```

returns

```
lame: excess arg Island of the Gods - 3.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Bash `for` loop is [not ideal](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for the results of `find` or `ls`. There are [other ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/298607).

You may want to use `-print0` and `xargs` to avoid word splitting issues.

```
$ find [path] -type f -name *.flac -print0 | xargs -0 [command line {xargs puts in fn}]
```

Or use `-exec` primary in find:

```
$ find [path] -type f -name *.flac -exec [process {find puts in fn}] \;
```

Alternative, you can use a `while` loop:

```
find [path] -type f -name *.flac | while IFS= read -r fn; do  # fn not quoted here...
  echo "$fn"                                          # QUOTE fn here! 
  # body of your loop
done
```

Comment: The last example assumes that no file name contains newline characters. Even with that assumption, use `IFS= read -r fn` to be otherwise foolproof.

Comment: @chepner: agreed