# extract rar files to same folder name

Tags: shell, unix, unrar

I have many `.rar` folders within a particular directory. I want to extract contents of each `rar` folder in the same directory and all the extracted files of `rar` folder should be placed in the new folder with the same name as that of the `rar` folder name.

For example, if there are two `rar` files: `one.rar` and `two.rar`, then the script should create two folders of the same name: `one` and `two`. A folder named `one` should contain files extracted from `one.rar` and folder named `two` should contain files extracted from `two.rar`.

The command: **unrar e $filename** extracts all the contents of rar file but does not create a  destination folder.

If I use `unrar e $filename $DESTINATION_PATH`, then since there can be many `rar` files, manually creating the folder name in the destination path will take a lot of time. How can I achieve this with a shell script?

so far I have written only these lines:

```
loc="/home/Desktop/code"`  # this directory path contains all the rar files to be extracted  <br/>

for file in "$loc"/* 
do               
unrar e $file
done
```

I don't know how to create the same folder name as of `rar` name and extract all files of that `rar` in the newly created folder of the same name.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to remove the file extension from your archives. Look at the following script which sets `destination` to the corresponding name.

```
#!/bin/sh

for archive in "$(find $loc -name '*.rar')"; do
  destination="$( echo $archive | sed -e 's/.rar//')"
  if [ ! -d "$destination" ] ; then mkdir "$destination"; fi
  unrar e "$archive" "$destination"
done
```

If you're using `bash`, then you can simply use

```
#!/bin/bash

for archive in "$(find $loc -name '*.rar')"; do
  destination="${archive%.rar}"
  if [ ! -d "$destination" ] ; then mkdir "$destination"; fi
  unrar e "$archive" "$destination"
done
```

Comment: This method does not work when the file name has a white space. Better use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612560

Comment: +1 @wouter205 Comment - The For Loop has its Restrictions and i have faced issues with it , Right way to go is as u suggested Find and While do Loop - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612560 , Kudos :)

Comment: @BetaCoder you're welcome, it did take me some time to figure it out so I wanted to help others to prevent this :-)