# extract all rar files in a folder and sub-folder to same folder

Tags: bash, find, unrar

I found this post for extracting rar files from one folder to same folder name:  [extract rar files to same folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749246/extract-rar-files-to-same-folder-name/45749549#45749549?newreg=722e826eef734393b79abf759244eff9)

I want to extract several rar files in sub-folders to sub-folders of the same name i.e.

`/folder/sub-folder1/file1.rar --> /folder/sub-folder1/new-folder-same-name-as-sub-folder1/extracted_files.xyz`

`/folder/sub-folder2/file2.rar --> /folder/sub-folder2/new-folder-same-name-as-sub-folder2/extracted_files.xyz`

How do I modify:

```
#!/bin/bash

    for archive in "$(find $loc -name '*.rar')"; do
      destination="${archive%.rar}"
      if [ ! -d "$destination" ] ; then mkdir "$destination"; fi
      unrar e "$archive" "$destination"
    done
```

to do this i.e. run for all rar files in folder/*rar?  Or, use something similar?

Thanks

Comment: You can try `mkdir -p $destination` if i have understood the question well..If you want to have `sub-folder2/sub-folder2/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use next pipe from the `$loc` folder, which path do you expect in filename:

```
find . -iname *.sh -type f -printf '%P\n' | xargs -i bash -c 'echo "$1" `dirname $1`/`echo "$1" | sed "s/\.sh$//1" | tr "/" "-"`' -- {}
```

As you can see, `$(dirname $archive)` will return you a directory path, and pipe `sed "s/\.sh$//1" | tr "/" "-"` can return you a `filename` in expected format for you.

Comment: Thanks that sounds right - will give that a go today