# Recurse files with find and show progress

Tags: bash, macos, shell, macos-sierra

Someone gave me this to recursively expand folder placeholders:

```
exec 7>&1
output="go"
while [ "$output" ]; do
    output=$(find . -name "*.cloudf" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 python odrive.py sync | tee /dev/fd/7)
done
```

(`.cloudf` are [odrive](http://odrive.com) placeholder files; the `sync` command expands them into folders, and these new folders will then contain more `.cloudf` placeholders which need to expanded.)

It works. The problem is that after running it a few times, it stops showing its progress.

The `exec 6>&1` and `tee /dev/fd/6` are supposed to be some kind of trick for showing progress ... but they only work once or twice, then they stop working.

I tried changing the `6` to `7` and other numbers, but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your command line or what "odrive" or `.cloudf` files might be for, but if you open a redirection with `exec 7>&1`, you may rant to close it when you're done with `exec 7>&-`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that; still not printing progress...

Answer (score 0):

This works (albeit with some extra blank lines):

```
while [[ -n $(find . -name '*.cloudf') ]]; do 
   find . -name "*.cloudf" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P $p python odrive.py sync; 
done
```

(With the help of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46541/how-can-i-use-bashs-if-test-and-find-commands-together) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find))

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the issue of your missing output through `tee`. It doesn't even use fancy redirection. But anyway .. if you've solved your problem with this, please mark the answer as correct to "close" the question.