# For loop for result of "find" command

Tags: bash, find

I have this find command:

```
$ find . -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Hls BuildConfig {} \;
```

I need to execute this command for each result of command find above:

```
$ zip -d RESULTPATH "*/BuildConfig.class"
```

So can I do this with for loop or not? Can I create .sh file that will be doing what I need?
Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/1531971

Comment: Is `RESULTPATH` intended to be "each of the files identified by the `find` command"? Also, a `.jar` file is a zip. Do you mean `grep -z`? Also, what's with the quotes on your `zip` line?

Comment: yes, on resultpath's place must be the paths that was found by find command. Quotes are missing

Comment: Sounds like you want to grep through not the jar file itself, but the list of filenames it contains. That requires a rather different command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grep` command has two channels for information out of it. The first and most obvious one is of course `stdout`, where it sends matches it finds. But if it finds *no* matches, it also uses an exit value > 0 to inform you. Combined with the `-q` (quiet) option, you can use this as a more intelligent option for `find`:

```
$ find . -name '*.jar' -exec zgrep -sq BuildConfig {} \; -exec zip -d {} "*/BuildConfig.class" \;
```

This assumes that you want to search through the compressed file using `grep -Z`, of course. :)

Or for easier reading:

```
find . -name '*.jar' \
  -exec zgrep -sq BuildConfig {} \; \
  -exec zip -d {} "*/BuildConfig.class" \;
```

Find operates by running each test in order. You can think of the options as a series of filters; the `-name` option is the first filters, and a file only gets passed to the second `-exec` if the preceding `-exec` exited without errors.

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to run a command for each result of a `grep` command with `xargs`, is using the `-Z` or `--null` flag with `grep` to make the results terminated by null, and the `-0` flag with `xargs` so that it expects values terminated by null, like this:

```
find . -name '*.jar' -exec grep -Z BuildConfig {} \; | xargs -0 zip -d RESULTPATH "*/BuildConfig.class
```

I removed the `Hls` flags because they all seem pointless (even harmful) in your use case.

But I'm afraid this will not actually work for your case,
because a `.jar` file is usually a binary file (zipped archive of Java classes),
so I don't think the `grep` will ever match anything. You can give [zgrep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/zgrep.1.html) a try to search inside the jars.

Comment: it will still contain plain text names for directories.