# How to add many SSL certificates for Java application inside docker?

Tags: java, bash, docker, dockerfile, ssl-certificate

I'm new in docker. I want to add several certificates for Java application inside Docker. I'm using this code in Dockerfile:

```
RUN keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias artifactory -file /files/cert.crt -keystore local -storepass changeit
```

and it works fine, but only for one certificate. How I can add all certificates from /files folder with one line command or in some cycle or maybe with bash file?

UPDATED: I used next bash to add certificates:

```
for cert in ${tempdir}/*.crt; do
cert2=$(basename $cert)
echo "# ${cert2}" >> ${destdir}/${cert2}
${openssl} x509 -inform der -in ${cert} -outform pem -out ${destdir}/${cert2}
keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias artifactory -file /${destdir}/${cert2} -keystore local -storepass changeit
done
```

but got next error: "keytool: command not found". The command keytool works fine when I run it in the docker container.

Comment: Install jdk/jre on the build-computer, it has keytool executable.

Comment: Java is already installed. I can run keytool manually in the docker container. But when I try to do this via bash I get the error. Maybe syntax in bash file is wrong.

Comment: It might be very well be a PATH-problem. Try `which keytool` in terminal, to find out where the executable is.

Comment: You right about java. I inspected carefully my code and find that java installed after the bash code called. It's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dockerfile call bash file:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash openssl wget && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY getcerts.sh getcerts.sh
RUN chmod +x getcerts.sh && ./getcerts.sh
```

Bash script:

```
for cert in ${tempdir}/*.crt; do
keytool -importcert -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias artifactory-${cert2} -file /${destdir}/${cert2} -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a keystore. But it is recommended to use the default KeyStore.
**default keystore path:**
`<c:\JavaCAPS>\appserver\domains\<MyDomain>\config\keystore.jks`

but if you need you can create a keystore.

**Generate a Java keystore and key pair**

`keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048`

**Import a root or intermediate CA certificate to an existing Java keystore**

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file Thawte.crt -keystore keystore.jks`

**Import a signed primary certificate to an existing Java keystore**

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore keystore.jks`

**Saving a Symmetric Key Programmatically**

```
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secret = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter password = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pwdArray);
ks.setEntry("db-encryption-secret", secret, password);
```

first parameter is the key alias, second parameter is certificate key and third one is the password.

read more:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggfen/index.html
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

Comment: I see here how I can to add only one file. But my question was how to add several files in a simple way - command line or cycle.

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically ?

Comment: No matter how. If there is no simple command it may be programmatically.

Comment: I've edited my answer and add programmatical code. try it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand, that you want to automate the import of multiple certificates. You can do so by looping over the files with bash.

As here described, you can search for files via find an then process the result.

[How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find/9612232)

To do so you could code your keytool command in it's own bash script and send the result of the find command them to your script, with something like

```
find . -name *.crt -print0 | xargs -0 myImportScript.sh
```

If you have that accomplished you can make the import script available, e.g. via a symlink, and let docker RUN the command above.

Answer (score 0):

Download the certificate

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername NAME -connect www.google.com:443 |\
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > gcert.crt
```

Copy to Docker:

```
docker cp SRC_PATH CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

Import to Java keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias www.google.com -file CERT_FILE_PATH -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -trustcacerts
```

For complete steps, refer:
http://muralitechblog.com/import-ssl-certificate-into-java-keystore/