# How to iterate over a directory and display only filename

Tags: bash

I would want to iterate over contents of a directory and list only ordinary files.
The path of the directory is given as an user input. The script works if the input is current directory but not with others.
I am aware that this can be done using ls.. but i need to use a for .. in control structure.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter the path:"

read path

contents=$(ls $path)

for content in $contents
do
   if [ -f $content ];
   then
       echo $content
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls` is only returning the file names, not including the path. You need to either:

1. Change your working directory to the path in question, or
2. Combine the path with the names for your `-f` test

Option #2 would just change:

```
    if [ -f $content ];
```

to:

```
    if [ -f "$path/$content" ];
```

Note that there are other issues here; `ls` may make changes to the output that break this, depending on wrapping. If you insist on using `ls`, you can at least make it (somewhat) safer with:

```
contents="$(command ls -1F "$path")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing this properly:

Either loop through the * pattern and test file type:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter the path:"

read -r path

for file in "$path/"*; do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Or using find to iterate a null delimited list of file-names:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Enter the path:"

read -r path

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  echo "$file"
done < <(
  find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0
)
```

The second way is preferred since it will properly handle files with special characters and offload the file-type check to the find command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file`, set to search for files (`-type f`) from $path directory:

```
   find "$path" -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path=
while [[ ! $path ]]; do
    read -p "Enter path: " path
done

for file in "$path"/*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

If you want to traverse all the subdirectories recursively looking for files, you can use [globstar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in "$path"/**; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

In case you are looking for specific files based on one or more patterns or some other condition, you could use the `find` command to pick those files.  See this post:

[How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/6862601)

## Related

- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067266/6862601)
- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [Is double square brackets [[ ]] preferable over single square brackets [ ] in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601)