# Bash find replace multiple files to NEW files

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, find

I have a directory of let's call them template files.
They have one value in them that needs to be substituted.
I wanted a pristine folder with a 'keyword' in the substitution place in each file.
I wanted to substitute the word and output all files to a new folder with files named the same as the input.
The command that I found here is:

```
find . -name '*.sql' -i -exec sed -e 's/TEXTTOSUBSTITUTE/SUBSTITUTIONTEXT/g' {} \;
```

How can I get this command to output files to another directory and leave the originals unchanged?
thank you so much for your help!
I want the original files to remain unchanged. the folder is called Templates and the folder in the same directory as the directory Templates is called Usefiles. The template files act as the base files and so should not change. I guess I could use the suggestion above, but do 2 separate find commands, one to copy and the other to sed in the new directory
UPDATE>>>>
I've been trying the suggestions, but the sed doesn't seem to work.  The copy works, but the sed is a variable and is coming out blank in the script.
Here is my current, and thanks again!! :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Year i.e. 2020"
read -p reportyear
echo "Enter Month i.e. 04"
read -p reportmonth
SUBSTITUTIONTEXT=$reportyear/$reportmonth

find MOT/ -name '*.sql' -exec sh -c 'for f; do
 echo cp -v "$f" MOU/ && echo sed -ie "s/TEXTTOSUBSTITUTE/$SUBSTITUTIONTEXT/g" MOU/"${f##*/}"
done' _ {} +
```

FINAL UPDATE
Thanks to you guys, a working solution:

```
echo "Enter Year i.e. 2020"
read reportyear
echo "Enter Month i.e. 04"
read reportmonth
SUBSTITUTIONTEXT=$reportyear\/$reportmonth
cd /to/relevant/files
find MOT/ -name '*.sql' -exec sh -c 'for f; do 
cp -v "$f" MOU/ && sed -i 's@SUBSTITUTIONYEARMONTH@"$SUBSTITUTIONTEXT"@' MOU/"${f##*/}" 
done' _ {} + > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is *another directory* in the same folder as .sql files? And is `find` really required here, are there .sql files in subdirectories?

Comment: My answer currently the original files is copied to destination unchanged and edit the files in the current directory. That is how I understood your question.

Comment: Or I got the logic in reverse... :-(

Comment: Use a different delimiter for sed e.g. `"s,TEXTTOSUBSTITUTE,$SUBSTITUTIONTEXT,g"` basically the delimiter must not be in the string/regularexpression so you can choose any string, like a pipe `|` or what I have shown you a comma `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by the the question two directories `Template` as the `source` and  `Usedfiles` as the `destination`.

Using `find(1)`

```
find Templates/ -name '*.sql' -exec sh -c 'for f; do
 echo cp -v "$f" Usefiles/ && echo sed -ie "s/TEXTTOSUBSTITUTE/SUBSTITUTIONTEXT/g" Usefiles/"${f##*/}"
done' _ {} +
```

Another option is to use the shellopt `globstar` from `bash`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

for f in ./Templates/**/*.sql; do
 echo cp -v "$f" Usefiles/ && echo sed -ie 's/TEXTTOSUBSTITUTE/SUBSTITUTIONTEXT/g' Usefiles/"${f##*/}"
done
```

- Remove all the `echo` If you're satisfied with the result so It can actually do what needs to be done.
- See [Loop through files using find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find) and [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)
- See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for the `${f##*/}`
- See [Globstar](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) for the `shopt -s globstar`

Comment: Right, need to clarify from the OP,

Comment: I want the original files to remain unchanged.  the folder is called Templates and the folder in the same directory as the directory Templates is called Usefiles.  The template files act as the base files and so should not change. I guess I could use the suggestion above, but do 2 separate find commands, one to copy and the other to sed in the new directory.

Comment: Could you please update the question and add what you have posted here.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and parallel):

```
sub=2020/04
find Templates -name '*.sql'| parallel "sed 's#key#'"$sub"'#g' {} > Usefiles/{/}"
```

Set the substitute parameter in `sub`.

Pipe the find command to the parallel invocation.

Run sed against each file from the find command and substitute `$sub` for each `key` placing the output in a the directory `Usefiles` in the same directory as `Templates` with the same file name.