# For i in loop on file uses filename as well

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

So here is my problem when using code:

```
for i in filename.txt
do
    <operations>
    done
```

Operations are being made on both file contents as well as filename itself, why is that happening?

Just to be clear I alread got 2 solutions that solve this problem, but I still can't understand why is that happening.
One of the solutions that have worked for me:

```
for i in $(cat filename.txt)
do
    tar -czf ${i}.tar $i
rm -R $i
gzip $i.tar
    done
```

Comment: In `for i in filename.txt` you will have one `$i` and it will be set to `filename.txt`. What are you asking about exactly?

Comment: Ted- No, in filename.txt there is list that is used in for loop. I want to read every line in that file and do operations(packing, removing etc.) on them and it works exactly like that except it also does operation on "filename.txt" itself as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472

Comment: Then you should do: `while read -r line; do ...operations using $line... ; ...etc...; done < file.txt`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: "file contains a line "filename.txt" as well" it does?

Comment: You need a [mcve]. Don't just brush aside the body of the loop with `<operations>`. Provide an *actual* body that reproduces the problem you are seeing.

Comment: chepner- sorry, I've corrected my question

Comment: @MichałBroda Yes. In `for i in filename.txt` you will have one `$i` and it will be set to `filename.txt`. If you want to read the contents of `$i` - do that in the loop.

Comment: Thank you all, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes. In for i in filename.txt you will have one $i and it will be set to filename.txt. If you want to read the contents of $i - do that in the loop."
Thank you Ted Lyngmo.