# How to insert a generated value by a loop while you open a file in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

Lets say that I have:

```
cat FILENAME1.txt
Definition john 
cat FILENAME2.txt
Definition mary
cat FILENAME3.txt
Definition gary

cat  textfile.edited
text
text 
text
```

I want to obtain an ouput like:

```
1 john text
2 mary text
3 gary text
```

I tried to use "stored" values from FILENAMES "generated" by a loop. I wrote this:

```
for file in $(ls *.txt); do


        name=$(cat $file| grep -i Definition|awk '{$1="";print $0}')
        #echo $name  --> this command works as it gives the names

done 

        cat textfile.edited|  awk  '{printf "%s\t%s\n",NR,$0}'
```

which very close to what I want to get

```
1   text
2   text 
3   text
```

My issue was coming through when I tried to add the "stored" value. I tried the following with no success.

```
cat textfile.edited|  awk  '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$name,NR,$0}' 

cat textfile.edited|  awk  '{printf "%s\t%s\n",name,NR,$0}'

cat textfile.edited|  awk -v name=$name '{printf "%s\t%s\n",NR,$0}'
```

Sorry if the terminology used is not the best, but I started scripting recently.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @oguzismail thnx for the answer.  Unfortunately, this command prints the same output as  cat textfile.edited|  awk  '{printf "%s\t%s\n",NR,$0}' having tab delimiter at the beginning

Comment: `for file in $(ls *.txt);` is better written as `for file in *.txt;`, btw. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Are you always going to have the same number of FILENAMEx.txt files as lines in the textfile.edited one?

Comment: @Shawn .Thanks for the link/suggestion!.... No the lines are not the same as the number of files.

Comment: @KGee: So you need to explain what to do, if they don't match

Comment: @Shawn ops!! Sorry I would like to wrote  "the No the lines are the same as the number of files....

Comment: @Inian ... i  did a mistake in my previous post with Shawn .... thanx for telling me.

Comment: wish this could be sticky somewhere, could post that in nearly every second comment [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly, David A. Wheeler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution using `paste` and `awk` ...

We'll append a count to the lines in  `textfile.edited` (so we can see which lines are matched by `paste`):

```
$ cat textfile.edited
text1
text2
text3
```

First we'll look at the `paste` component:

```
$ paste <(egrep -hi Definition FILENAME*.txt) textfile.edited
Definition john text1
Definition mary text2
Definition gary text3
```

From here `awk` can do the final slicing-n-dicing-n-numbering:

```
$ paste <(egrep -hi Definition FILENAME*.txt) textfile.edited | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print NR,$2,$3}'
1       john    text1
2       mary    text2
3       gary    text3
```

**NOTE**: It's not clear (to me) if the requirement is for a space or tab between the 2nd and 3rd columns; above solution assumes a tab, while using a space would be doable via a (`awk`) `printf` call.

Comment: Works perfectly!!! thanks a lot. In this way I will avoid messing with stored values

Answer (score 1):

You can do all with one `awk` command.
First file is the `textfile.edited`, other files are mentioned last.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {text[NR]=$0;next}
     /^Definition/ {namenr++; names[namenr]=$2}
     END { for (i=1;i<=namenr;i++) printf("%s %s %s\n", i, names[i], text[i]);}
     ' textfile.edited FILENAME*.txt
```

You can avoid `awk` with

```
paste -d' ' <(seq $(wc -l <textfile.edited)) \
            <(sed -n 's/^Definition //p' FILE*) \
            textfile.edited
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tested it and works. The only reason why accept another answer was that your way was a bit complicated for my level.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using GNU utilities:

```
paste -d ' ' <(cat -n FILENAME*.txt | sed 's/\sDefinition//') textfile.edited
```

---

Or,

```
paste -d ' ' <(cat -n FILENAME*.txt | sed 's/^\s*//;s/\sDefinition//') textfile.edited
```

if the leading white spaces are not desired.

---

Alternatively:

```
paste -d ' ' <(sed 's/^Definition\s//' FILENAME*.txt | cat -n) textfile.edited
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!!!  You indicated another way of dealing with paste and sed... Im surprised!!!  The only reason why I accepted markp-fusos' answer over yours was only that he posted first!  Both ways were understandable for a "new kid on the block" like me

Answer (score 1):

Another version of the `paste` solution with a slightly careless `grep` -

```
$: paste -d\  <( grep -ho '[^ ]*$' FILENAME?.txt ) textfile.edited
john text
mary text
gary text
```

Or, one more way to look at it...

```
$: a=( $(sed '/^Definition /s/.* //;' FILENAME[123].txt) )
$: echo "${a[@]}"
john mary gary

$: b=( $(<textfile.edited) )
$: echo "${b[@]}"
text text text

$: c=-1 # initialize so that the first pre-increment returns 0
$: while [[ -n "${a[++c]}" ]]; do echo "${a[c]} ${b[c]}"; done
john text
mary text
gary text
```

This will put all the values in memory before printing anything, so if the lists are really large it might not be your best bet. If they are fairly small, it's pretty efficient, and a single parallel index will keep them in order.

If the lines are not the same as the number of files, what did you want to do? As long as there aren't more files than lines, and any extra lines are ok to ignore, this still works. If there are more files than lines, then we need to know how you'd prefer to handle that.

Comment: Thank you very much... The second way was a bit complicated for my level... But I will keep the " while"  way for the future... Im not confident to deal with storing values but in a way I have to learn to do so!

Comment: Worth practicing. Arrays are a great tool. ;) Good, luck, and have fun!