# How do I flatten out a directory and rename my files?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have a huge directory that is made up of a lot of sub-directories.
How do I flatten the images in such a way that they appear on top of the other, and rename them to the subdirectory they were in?

For example, how to rename `dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/XYZ.jpg` to `dir1__dir2__dir4.jpg` using $bash?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
find . -name '*.jpg' -print0 | while read -d '' file
do
  target="${file#./}" # remove './' at the beginning
  target="${target%\/*}" # remove '/*' at the end
  target="${target//\//_}.jpg" # replace '/' by '_' and add '.jpg'
  mv "$file" "$target" # do the moving
done
```

This is basically a combination of two things: [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find) and [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion).