# How to save `find -exec` result and used to compare `FILE OWNER`,regardless white space file name?

Tags: bash, permissions, find, compare, exec

```
find . -depth -exec stat --format '%n %U %G' {} + | sort -d > acl_file_old
#some days later,do it again,and then compare
find . -depth -exec stat --format '%n %U %G' {} + | sort -d > acl_file_new
while read FILE OWNER GROUP; do
    while read FILE_NEW OWNER_NEW GROUP_NEW; do
    if [[ $FILE == $FILE_NEW ]]; then
    echo "$FILE"
    break
    done < $result_dir/acl_file_new
done < $result_dir/acl_file_old
```

Run above bash script,When file name has white space,such as `my file here`,`while read FILE` works not well.

I already read similar [post1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names),[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find),I know looping over find's output is bad practice.The problem is I need save `find -exec` result `acl_file_old` first.

How to save `find -exec` result and used to compare `FILE OWNER`,regardless white space file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read command assigns the words found on the line to the variables.

Note that the last variable is assigned with all the chars remaining up to the end of the line.

The first quick win would be to change the order and make sure that the filename is located at the end with `... -exec stat --format '%U %G %n' {} + ...`

Then change the order of the variables to `while read -r OWNER GROUP FILE ; do ...`

It there are more fancy chars this would be broken anyway. Maybe for   (space) it would do the trick ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What else fancy chars would broken?

Comment: I was thinking of new line char in the filename itself or some chars that could  be interpreted by the shell ...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the separator when you write to the file:

```
find . -depth -exec stat --format '%n;%U;%G' {} + | sort -d > file
```

And read from it using `IFS=";"`:

```
while IFS=";"; read FILE OWNER GROUP; do
echo $FILE
done < file
```

(you can use characters other than `;` too)