# In bash, I want to save name of files in list. Any solutions?

Tags: bash

I want to save all filename in ~/mount that is a csv file. Below is my code

```
 #!/bin/bash


IFS=$'\n' ARR=`find ~/mount -name '*.csv'`;
for VALUE in "${ARR[@]}";
do
    echo "<----$VALUE---->";
done
```

This should print out

```
<----foo.csv---->
<----bar.csv---->
```

but instead, it prints out

```
<----foo.csv
bar.csv---->
```

How can I fix this? or is there another way?
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612090/how-to-loop-through-file-names-returned-by-find)

Comment: @JulienSorin This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @chi.ho : You need to define an array. Your variable `ARR` is a scalar, but in the `for` statement, you use it as if it were an array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are defined by using

```
name=( .... )
```

Hence, you could define

```
ARR=( $(find .... ) )
```

Perhaps a better alternative would be to not use `find` at all:

```
shopt -s globstar # to enable **
ARR=( ~/mount/**/*.csv )
shopt -u globstar
```

This would even catch the border case, that you have filenames with embedded newline characters.

Comment: Did you mean `extglob` or `globstar`? Also, what if the user already has `shopt -s globstar` in their bashrc? You wouldn't want to undo it.

Comment: Ah, you are right - from the man page, I see that it is globstar. I didn't notice, because my bash (version 4.4.12(3)) strangely expands `**` in this way, even if extglob and globstar are off; don't know why. The `.bashrc` should not matter, because the code seems to be used in a script, and .bashrc is only relevant in interactive shells. Furthermore, if the use indeed has set this switch before, he likely knows enough on that subject that he doesn't need any handholding for restoring the original value.